# Get tuple of field query value

Tags: python, django

I want to get ids of some objects. What is the clean way to get them in tuple?

A .values() queryset return this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name__startwith='A').values('id')
>>>> [{'id': 20L}, {'id': 21L}, {'id': 84L}]
```

And i would like  transform/get them into a tuple like:

```
(20L, 21L, 84L)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to get `values_list` with `flat=True`

```
models.MyModel.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
```

> This is similar to values() except that instead of returning dictionaries, it returns tuples when iterated over. Each tuple contains the value from the respective field passed into the values_list() call — so the first item is the first field, etc.
>
> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. An example should make the difference clearer:

Comment: Thank's it look okay but it don't work with MySQL (Error raised: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

Comment: You question doesn't have this limitation, sorry

Answer (score 2):

What about a generator expression?

```
tuple(d['id'] for d in MyModel.objects.filter(name__startwith='A').values('id'))
```

Alternatively:

```
import operator
tuple(map(lambda x: operator.getitem(x, 'id'), MyModel.objects.filter(name__startwith='A').values('id'))
```

Or, as an answer that was deleted for some reason suggested, you could do this:

```
tuple(object.id for object in MyModel.objects.filter(name__startwith='A'))
```

Alternatively:

```
import operator
getter = operator.attrgetter('id')
tpl = tuple(map(getter, MyModel.objects.filter(name__startwith='A')))
```